# Get Response by FatSecret API 2.0 C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I managed to get the token through this guide: https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth2, but I couldn't get responce correctly. Where did I go wrong in the code?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void BtnFoodApi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // --- Get Token --

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("9276456b47524b479cbdaf7cf5792bbf:0366d2fc646e4b6f89bf11bddbaec6a4");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "scope", "basic" },
           { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString));
        var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);


        // --- Get responce --

        var http = new HttpClient();

        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", data.access_token);

        var valuesRequest = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "application", "json" },
        };

        var contentRequest = new FormUrlEncodedContent(valuesRequest);

        var responseRequest = await http.PostAsync("https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api", contentRequest);
        
        //Parameters: method=foods.search&search_expression=toast&format=json // How can I call Api 2.0 with these parameters?

        //var responseRequestString = await responseRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string access_token { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int expires_in { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get to the `responseRequest` String string in JSON string.

At the bottom of [this page](https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth2) there is the guide about this step and I tried to write it in C# but incorrectly.

Comment: Can you check your responseRequest object's status code, headers, etc. to make sure it looks like a successful request? What do you get in the responseRequestString - is it JSON, and you just need to parse it into your class (I don't see any code that does this) or is it an error message, or something else?

Comment: (Oops, I meant `Accept:` singular.)

Comment: Oh, OK - so it is an authentication error? Can you edit the response about the token into your question please?

Comment: I've just tried your code (using your credentials) and I'm getting response back as 400 Bad Request, `{"error":"invalid_client"}`. Is that what you're seeing? I don't know what that means, sorry. You might have to ask them.
`

Comment: I removed the incorrect phrase about the token.

Comment: I have update the keys: var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("9276456b47524b479cbdaf7cf5792bbf:9c7f0eb281aa499d8c8644165d90d56e");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to base64-encode your Bearer token - that's only used to obfuscate Basic authentication. You can use the string as-is.

```
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", data.access_token);
```

Comment: Note you're also reading responseRequestString from the wrong request object: that should be responseRequest not request. And if that's solved the problem you should also regenerate your API secret so that it's not posted on the web for anyone to find, even if it is IP-restricted.

Comment: I corrected what you told me. But now the only error left: "Invalid signature: oauth_signature '0366d2fc646e4b6f89bf11bddbaec6a4'" What should I put in "oauth_signature". I have tried with the Client Secret - Client ID - Consumer Key and Consumer Secret, but none is the correct solution. (I have update the question)

Comment: You're using OAuth 2 aren't you, not OAuth 1? As far as I can tell you shouldn't have to add a signature. If you really do need one then you'll have to compute it per-request using the algorithm in the documentation (which is on the OAuth 1 page, not OAuth 2.)

Comment: This is what I actually don't understand: how should I ask the question with: REST API OAuth 2.0. I update the question as far as I can, but then I need help to complete

Comment: I don't know the API sorry. I'd guess put the parameters back as a query string, make it a GET request not a POST, and just send the Bearer token as authentication.